# Drawer Icon on React Native Mixed Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react navigation for an app. I combined tab and drawer navigation with drawer navigation being the root navigation. It works fine. But i'm having issue with placing drawer icon for the tab navigation screen inside the drawer. How can i possibly display icon for the drawer item for tab navigation screen.

```
const rootNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Discover: Discover,
    Nearby: IndexMap,
},
{
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            let iconName;
            if (routeName === 'Discover') {
                iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
            } else if (routeName === 'Nearby') {
                iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
            // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
        },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
});
const AppDrawNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({

    Home: rootNav,
    Profile: Profile,
    List: List,
    Bookmarks: Bookmark,
    Payments: StackNav,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
    Support: Support,
}, 
{
    contentComponent: props => (
        <CustomDrawerComponent {...props} navigation={props.navigation} />
    ),
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'orange'
    }
},
{
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        drawerIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            let iconName;
            if (routeName === 'Home') {
                iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
            } else if (routeName === 'Nearby') {
                iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
            // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
        },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution..This solves it:

```
rootNav.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: "Home",
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }: TabScene) =><FontAwesome name='home' style = {{fontSize:24, color:tintColor}}  />,
  drawerLabel: "Home",
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }: TabScene) =><FontAwesome name='home' style = {{fontSize:24, color:tintColor}}  />
};
```